# Update activity UI on sms received from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, list, broadcast, receiver

1. I have an  `SMSlist_activity.java` that displays the list of an sms-conversation.
2. I have an `sms_receiver.java` that is a broadcast receiver for incoming sms.

Now I want to update sms conversation list in `SMSlist_activity.java` when an sms received via `sms_receiver.java`, of course this update will just happens if the `SMSlist_activity.java` is running and visible.

If anyone has an idea, I will be glad to here that.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution with Broadcast receivers.
int sms_receiver.java, when sms received, I broadcast an intent:

```
            Intent intent2 = new Intent();
            intent2.setAction("co.ir.ts.app.sms.smsumad");
            context.sendBroadcast(intent2);
```

In app manifest in SMSlist_activity.java definition I add Intent filter so my SMSlist_activity.java can receive broadcast:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SMSlist_activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="co.ir.ts.app.sms.smsumad" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now in SMSlist_activity.java main class define a broadcast receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //Updating UI here
    }
};
```

in  onResume method register the receiver created above:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
     filter.addAction("co.ir.ts.app.sms.smsumad");
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}
```

and finally in onPause method unregister the receiver:

```
 protected void onPause()
{
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
    if (isSentPending)
    {
        unregisterReceiver(sent);
    }
}
```